# AT command to retrieve user input on call on mobile phone

Tags: at-command

I know it is possible to answer a call on a mobile phone with the AT command set. But how can I see which number is calling?

After the call is answered I would like the dialer to enter a pin code. How can I retrieve this pin code at the opposite side? Is there an AT command to show what the dialer has entered?

Answer (score 1):

AT commands are used to control the phone and get notified about the phone events. There is nothing to interact with the user, just the phone. So you can surely answer a call using

```
ATA -> answers the call
AT+CLIP -> set the caller id presentation
```

In order to see who's calling you have to enable the caller id presentation. The command syntax is sometimes non-standard so my advice is to look on your brand AT manual.

Comment: I need to develop an auto answering (GSM call) Android application, I searched internet and learned that 3rd party applications do not have permission "android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE", because of which my application can not auto answer a call, now I am reading about these AT commands. Can you please tell me one thing, which I didn't find, can a 3rd party application use these AT commands, on rooted/unrooted phone to auto answer phone call...?

Comment: @user1204089 I'm not an Android developer (yet). Usually AT commands are sent over a serial port (either USB or a RFCOMM bluetooth connection). Did you already check out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740223/android-auto-answer-the-incoming-call-programatically

Comment: Yes, now I have used that, keydown event, approach.