# Auto answer the incoming call programmatically?

Tags: android, phone-call, incoming-call

I have the code for getting the number of the incoming call to a android phone. But I want to automatically answer the call when the incoming call is from a particular number.

I found this code on the internet:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = null;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phoneNr = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: " + phoneNr);
        String numb = "+4348873541";

        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        if (phoneNr.equals(numb)) {
            ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how to auto answer the call from a particular number?

Comment: I tried this code, but does not seem to work. Im using Samsung Galaxy, android version 2.2. Do you think it is because of the version???

Comment: Unfortunately bluetooth solution works not in all cases - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195140/1770426

Answer (score 8):

As from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765980/android-how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call)

Check this [source](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java)

> They send a Bluetooth "keydown" event to answer the call!

Comment: +1 for not blindly copying the link, but explaining the idea on how they do it.